# Focus Nearest Div of Select Element

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-tokeninput, tokenize2

I have select element

```
  <select id="tokenize" multiple="multiple" 
class="tokenize" style="margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px; border: 0px; display: none;"/>
```

Under select element there is div with it is class

```
<div class="tokenize Tokenize">
<ul class="TokensContainer ui-sortable">
<li class="Placeholder" style="display: list-item;">
enter Position</li><li class="TokenSearch">
<input size="5"></li></ul><ul class="Dropdown"
 style="display: none;"></ul></div>
```

I want to focus(with cursor) that div which is nearest to select.That div created dynamically via javascript so I can not fix it from html so I try javascript.I want to focus div(it is class tokenize) which is nearest select element(it is id tokenize)

I try this but this not work

```
  document.getElementById(Select-Element-ID).firstElementChild.focus().select();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the `tabindex` attribute to the div to make it focusable.
Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex

UPDATE:

```
var $inputToFocus = document.getElementById(Select-Element-ID).nextElementSibling.querySelector('.TokenSearch input');

$inputToFocus.focus();
```

Comment: But that div(whic class name is tokenize) is generated by third party jquery plugin,I try yo understand it but it is too complex

Comment: Thank,I added your code it does not give error but it does not focus .... http://pratikisara.com/Home/Quick  you can see here (title: Mesleğiniz/Unvan  in right there title there is select like text area,it is autocomplete,you can inpu "yaz" and then select any item then your code work but it does not focus )

Comment: Ok, you are trying to update the wrong element. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks @giovanni Giordano

Answer (score 0):

**This is the most advanced solution of your problem using Jquery..**
and yet very simple

$("#tokenize").closest("div").focus();